# How to Stitch Images in a folder in python

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to stitch two images to each other horizontally and I want to do this for all images in a folder. I have images named as:
img1.jpg
img1a.jpg
img2.jpg
img2a.jpg

So that img1 and img1a should be stitched and img2 should be stitched with img2a.

I am using the following code two stitch two images manually but couldn't implement how to extend it to the entire folder.

I would appreciate any help.

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

images = map(Image.open, ['img1.jpg', 'img1a.jpg'])
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

x_offset = 0
for im in images:
  new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
  x_offset += im.size[0]

new_im.save('img1.jpg')
```

Comment: use `os.listdir(folder)` to get all files in folder. Problem can be to creae pairs - but if they are alphabetic order then you can get `files[0:2]` , `files[2:3]` , etc. And then run your code with every pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that in folder are only pairs to stitch.

Use `os.listdir(folder)` to get all files in folder. Set them in alphabetic order using `sorted()` (sometimes `listdir()` gives files in different order - probably sorted by time of creation)

Using `zip()` and two sublists `all_files[::2]`, `all_files[1::2]` you can create pairs which you can run with your code

```
for a, b in zip(all_files[::2], all_files[1::2]):
     stitch(a, b)
```

---

```
import os
import sys
from PIL import Image

def stitch(name1, name2):
    images = map(Image.open, [name1, name2])
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

    total_width = sum(widths)
    max_height = max(heights)

    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

    x_offset = 0
    for im in images:
      new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
      x_offset += im.size[0]

    new_im.save(name1)

# ----

folder = 'some_folder'

# get all files in alphabetic order
all_files = sorted(os.listdir(folder))

# add folder to filename to have full path
all_files = [os.path.join(folder, name) for name in all_files]

# create pairs
for a, b in zip(all_files[::2], all_files[1::2]):
     stitch(a, b)
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also use `iter()` with `zip()` to create pairs

```
it = iter(all_files)
for a, b in zip(it, it):
    stitch(a, b)
```

or

Comment: Works great except it gave error for the .DS_Store file. so addition of all_files = os.listdir(path)
if '.DS_Store' in lst:
    all_files.remove('.DS_Store') make it work!

Comment: you could try `glob.glob(folder + "/*.jpg")` to get only jpg file and even with full path.